# Mass Updating Records in a collection to a Sharepoint list

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Hello Brilliant people,

I have spent the last 72 hours watching videos and reading Microsoft blogs to try and solve for the following use case.

UC1: Power app designed to allow for record updates of associated sharepoint list. This section is good to go.

UC2: allow mass update functionality for grouped functions that do not require much research.

Here is the visual:

[image]

In the data block at the bottom, please note that the fields of 'Note', 'Update_ts', and 'Auditor' are blank.  These are the rows in need added back into sharepoint based on the drop box selection in the header for all of the rows returned in the collection. I have been trying to use collections, passed to a power automate flow but I do not know how to add the individual items to each row of the collection.  Here are my collect statments

```
ClearCollect(
colMassEdit_1,
Filter(
    RBI_User_Actions,
    ESA_Action=MassEditDrp.SelectedText.Value
)
);
ClearCollect(
    colMassEdt_2,
        ShowColumns(colMassEdit_1,"Title","field_1","field_11","field_13","field_10","field_12","field_8","ID")
);
ClearCollect(
    colMassEdt_2a,
     RenameColumns(colMassEdt_2,"Title","Application","field_1","ESA_Action","field_10","Notes","field_11","Auditor","field_13","Update_ts","field_12","Status","field_8","FullName","ID","ID")
);
ClearCollect(upd_info, Statuslbl.Text,Update_ts.Text,'Auditor Name'.Text,Notes_Upd.Text)
```

I can get the first collection colMassEdt_2a into a JSON file for PowerAutomate, but I cannot get the items that need to be added for each record upd_info into the file.  Is there something I should be doing with Patch, or a for each type statment? I am lost and have tried every permutation that I can think of. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "ForAll" function? If you want to get every item from a gallery at the bottom, and patch it into SharePoint that could be helpful.